# subspaces, nullspace, column space, row space

Tags: linear-algebra

This question comes from the review for my exam tomorrow.

Suppose that A is an m x n matrix. For what value of k is Null A a subspace of R^k? For
what value of k is Row A a subspace of R^k? For what value of k is Col A a subspace of R^k?

The wording is a bit confusing. Do the indices for k have to exactly match?

Could someone give me an answer to at least one of these 3 questions so I have a better idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The indices *do not* have to match. In most cases, some of the indices *will not* match. For example, the columnspace of an $m\times n$ matrix is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$ since each column has $m$ entries and therefore are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Answer (score 0):

this matrix $A$ defines a transformation from $A:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$.  Think about where the Null Space and Column space live.  One is a kernel and one is an image/range.